# Illuminate\Database\QueryException plz help me out

Tags: laravel, mysql-connector

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException could not find driver (SQL: insert
>   into registration(fname,lname,email,password,_token)
>   values(rakesh,kumar,rakeshkumarsingh25may@gmail.com,fdzdv,4ZCltubm0q3sfU6a9jiEzrp7FlW19aWTIVQc0Ii4))

http://127.0.0.1:8000/store

```
 * @throws \Illuminate\Database\QueryException

 */

protected function runQueryCallback($query, $bindings, Closure $callback)

{

    // To execute the statement, we'll simply call the callback, which will actually

    // run the SQL against the PDO connection. Then we can calculate the time it

    // took to execute and log the query SQL, bindings and time in our memory.

    try {

        $result = $callback($query, $bindings);

    }



    // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error

    // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a

    // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.

    catch (Exception $e) {

        throw new QueryException(

            $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e

        );

    }



    return $result;

}
```

Comment: Error `could not find driver` is error when your php is missing Db driver. Could you tell me the php version you're using and your OS, I will find that command for you

Comment: You may check the mysql config.

Comment: I think it shoud be php problem (missing driver, need to install manually my command line), not mysql problem (missing `.sock`, access denied bla bla)

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

PHP version :
PHP 7.3.12-1 (cli) (built: Nov 28 2019 07:34:08) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.12, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.12-1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies